# Laravel 8.0 shopping cart with API

Tags: php, laravel-8, shopping-cart

I am developing a eCommerce shop application in Laravel 8.0. One task is to retrieve the product list from DB and display in products blade page.

Below is my controller implementation

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\Product;
    
    class ProductController extends Controller
    {
        //
    
        public function getProducts(){                
            $productList = Product::select("*")->where('active_flag','Y')->paginate(10);
            return response()->json(['productList'=>$productList]);
        }
    
        
    }
```

Also developed a api route and below is my api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('/products',[ProductController::class, 'getProducts']);
```

Below is my view products.blade page

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')

@section('content')
    <div class="container px-6 mx-auto">
        <h3 class="text-2xl font-medium text-gray-700">Product List</h3>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 mt-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4">
            
            <div class="w-full max-w-sm mx-auto overflow-hidden rounded-md shadow-md">
                
                <div class="flex items-end justify-end w-full bg-cover">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="px-5 py-3">
                    <h3 class="text-gray-700 uppercase">Product Name goes here</h3>
                    <span class="mt-2 text-gray-500">Product price goes here</span>
                    <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" value="product id goes here" name="id">
                        <input type="hidden" value="product name goes here" name="name">
                        <input type="hidden" value="product price goes here" name="price">
                        <input type="hidden" value="product img url goes here"  name="image">
                        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity">
                        <button class="px-4 py-2 text-white bg-blue-800 rounded">Add To Cart</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Now I want to get the json results through the api and show it in the blade page. But I don't know how to do that. Need some help in this. Hope my approach is correct and up to the standards..

Comment: Do you want to show the blade file on a mobile app?

Comment: In future there might be a requirement to integrate a mobile app. But for the moment its only the web app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render` method to get the blade content as a string for Illuminate, take a look over the next code

```
$content = view('user.create');

dd($content); // The result would be object of view
```

The previous code is invalid because it does not achieve our goal, so you can use the next code

```
$content = view('user.create')->render();

dump($content); // The result would be string

dump(json_encode($content)); // You can convert the result into JSON format
```